# Next and Previous month watcher in Vue FullCalendar

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, vuex

I'm using FullCalendar library with Vue.js

Is it possible to use the default prev, next and today buttons that are default to trigger my own actions.

I have created my customs buttons that do what I want, but prefer to use the default buttons.

Current I have a button linked to a method:

```
<button @click="handleMonthIncrement">Next Month</button>
```

And this calls this method:

```
 handleMonthIncrement: function(arg) {
  // update month and year
  this.incrementMonth();

  // update calendar
  let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi();
  calendarApi.next();

  // updateCurrentSummary (mapped to store)
  this.updateCurrentSummary();
}
```

I'm using the ref=fullCalendar which ties into the jQuery reference of the Calendar to change the view.

If I could listen to the next, prev buttons then I could remove that code as the buttons already change the calendar view.

Is this possible? I'm aware that viewRender (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/viewRender) can be used to note when the calendar has changed view, but am not sure if this is something that can be used for my requirements above.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Comment: which version of fullCalendar are you using, exactly? You've linked to the documentation for version 1, but that is ancient and long superseded. Most people are using either version 3, or the brand new version 4.

Comment: Yes you could use viewRender (v1-3) or viewSkeletonRender (v4) to help you - they occur whenever the view is changed (either switching view types, e.g. from month to week), and/or changing the displayed date range - that includes by pressing next/previous. So it covers more events than just those buttons, but you might find that's actually useful. And the view object provided in the callback tells you the date range of the view which is being rendered at that time.

Comment: One question though - why do you want to do this, exactly? if you are using it simply to know when to load events onto the calendar, then that's the wrong approach - instead you should declare a dynamic event source (there are a couple of ways to do that depending on your circumstances, documented [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) and [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function)

Comment: Hi @ADyson -- Using v.4 - will update my reference (sorry for inaccuracy!)

I'm not clear how I use viewSkeletonRender  callback in my Vue component. I tried to add the following prop in my Vue element like this: <FullCalendar @viewSkeletonRender="handleMonthChange" > but it doesn't trigger the method
handleMonthChange -- thanks for the help

Comment: Well I don't know anything about vue specifically unfortunately. Are you using the fullCalendar vue component as mentioned here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue ?

Comment: In reply to the question about Why: In addition to the calendar I have another component that calculates data about the current month. Eg. Shows the total: 10 events this month. I want this to change depending on what month is currently being displayed and can refresh this when the month is changed. That's why I want to trigger on month previous and next

Comment: Yep, I'm using the Vue component mentioned in that link. So far very good, just a bit stuck on this item.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an Emitted Event just like dateClick in their example on that link that would be monthChange or monthPrev etc.. but I can't find that, so looked into hooking into viewRender

Comment: Ok. Your approach seems fairly sensible then, assuming you're only ever using the "month" style of view and no others. I'm sorry I can't really help you a great deal more here, since I have absolutely no idea how vue works. According to the documentation on that component page, it looks like what you're doing with "viewSkeletonRender" ought to be correct, but that's about as much as I can tell you. "viewRender" doesn't exist in v4 so that will never work.

Comment: P.S. According to the [source code of the component](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-vue/blob/master/src/fullcalendar-options.js), viewSkeletonRender is there as an emitted event, so I'd be surprised if it doesn't work. Can you post your code? Maybe you could even make us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) (or a CodePen or JSFiddle if you prefer), so we can actually reproduce the issue and see it happening.

Comment: Although if I have understood the comments in that code, you could also try using it via props, since it seems to be saying it wants to deprecate some of them, including viewSkeletonRender, and move to specifying them as props instead. Given my limited (i.e. non-existent) vue knowledge, you might understand this better than me, but it seems like you might be able to try it either way.

Answer (score 5):

I achieved this by looking up the Events Emitted here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-vue/blob/master/src/fullcalendar-options.js

And I found datesRender - which can be added to the FullCalendar element prefaced by @ to trigger when the dates re-render. Because I have this on month only view I can then trigger a method which I called handleMonthChange.

See here:

```
<FullCalendar
  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
  @datesRender="handleMonthChange"
/>
```

Then within handleMonthChange I had the following:

```
handleMonthChange: function(arg) {
  var currentStart = arg.view.currentStart;
  var check = moment(currentStart, "YYYY/MM/DD");
  var currentMonth = check.format("M");

  // load action
  this.updateCurrentMonth(currentMonth);
  // refresh summaries
  this.updateSummary();
}
```

I used moment to determine the month from the date (from the view object.

See more info here on what is passed back here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesRender

I then used this to change the month in my Vuex state by calling a Vuex action, then I updated my summary section as required.

Hope that helps someone else too. Big thanks to @ADyson for helping me get here!

Comment: datesRender is now depreciated and is recommended to be used as a prop. I really don't understand how that works..